# How to add components on a panel using loop in Java?

Tags: java

I want to add some button, table on a panel and the number of button or panel are get from a text field input. That means I take input from the text field for how much button I add or how much table I add!

Here is my code (with error):

```
public class panel_scroll extends JFrame{

    JPanel main_panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel content_panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel action_panel = new JPanel();
    int range,i; 
    JButton btn = new JButton("Action");
    JTextField txt =  new JTextField(20);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(content_panel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    public panel_scroll(){
        init();
        cmp();
        btn_action();
    }

    private void btn_action(){
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                range = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().trim());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total button i required: "+range);
                for(i=1; i<=range; i++){
                    JButton (btn_i+""+i) = new JButton(); //i want to create button of different object but here what i have to do i dont understand//
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void init(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Panel with scroll bar");
    }

    private void cmp(){
        add(main_panel);
        main_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main_panel.add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        child_panel_work();
        main_panel.add(action_panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        action_panel_work();
    }

    private void action_panel_work(){
        action_panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
        action_panel.add(txt);
        action_panel.add(btn);
    }

    private void child_panel_work(){
        content_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        content_panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        panel_scroll obj = new panel_scroll();
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not code provider service. You have to specify the problem you are getting and people will help you to solve it. Nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: Yes i know but you may be don't understand what i want. And also you do not have any right to disgrace someone. Hope you understand!(Mangesh Ghotage)

Answer (score 0):

You can put them anonymously in a **list or array** and then populate the container with them

## Example

```
//define a list    
List<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
//use a loop to fill the list
for(i=1; i<=range; i++){
    listOfButtons.add( new JButton()); 
}
//then get the button at index 0 for example
listOfButtons.get(0);
```

or if you consider, you can use a `Map<String,JButton>` where the string is some kind of id, lets say the name of the button

Comment: a list is a collection, so you can have in there many objects of the same type... to put one inside do list.add()... and to get the button do list.get(x) where x is the index in the list... quite like an array...

Comment: ArrayList<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();range = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().trim());
             for(i=0; i<range; i++){
                 listOfButtons.add( new JButton()); 
             }
             button_add_action();GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  for(i=0; i<range; i++){
   c.gridx = 0;
   c.gridy = i;
   c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
   c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
   content_panel1.add(listOfButtons.get(i));
  }

Comment: when i write it: List<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>(); get>> The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <JButton>

Comment: And for this i write>>
 
ArrayList<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

Comment: yes, that error is cos you are using the wrong list... you are importing  *java.awt.List*... but you have to use the *java.util.List*... and the same for the ArrayList